# How to add a new user profile field to Dnn?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dnn9

I want to add a new profile field in the DNN portal to be displayed in the registration form. I could not find it inside the DNN portal menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in dnn7 go to this address : Admin -> Site Settings -> User Account Settings -> Profile Settings -> Add New Profile Property

in dnn9 go to this address : Settings -> Site Settings -> Site Behavior -> User Profile -> Add Field